# Cannot create Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, foreign-keys

I have a simple address book that collects people and companies info.
So I have the following 3 tables and then others like email, phonenumber, address linked to contact:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contact] (
    [ID]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Contatto] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person] (
    [ID]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [IdContact]    INT           NOT NULL,
    [IdCompany]     INT           NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_Company] FOREIGN KEY ([IdCompany]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Company] ([ID]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_Contact] FOREIGN KEY ([IdContact]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Contact] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company] (
    [ID]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [IdContact]  INT          NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Company] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Company_Contact] FOREIGN KEY ([IdContact]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Contact] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Basically I want that if someone deletes a contact also the person/company associated with it will be deleted. Also, if someone deletes the company associated to a person, the IdCompany of person must be set to null.

The constraint that cannot be created due to "loop creation or additional propagation path creation" is FK_Person_Contact.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the 'loop creation' is because the Person table references the Contact table and the Company table and the Company table also references the Contact table.

Can a Person record and a Company record reference different Contact records?

Person A -> Contact A
         -> Company A -> Contact B

Or should the Person record and the Company record reference the same Contact?

Person A -> Contact A
         -> Company A -> Contact A

How is the relationship between Contact, Person and Company defined?

- 1 Contact has many Persons?
- 1 Contact has many Companies?
- 1 Person has many Contacts?
- 1 Person has 1 Company?
- 1 Person has many Companies?
- 1 Company has many Contacts?
- 1 Company has many Persons?

It may be you need to think about one or more link tables to model the relationship properly.

Comment: A contact refers or to a person or to a company.  
So Person and company cannot refer to the same contact.  
To contact several address/phonenumber/email are connected.  
Person.IdCompany may refer to a company(if it works for that company).  
May I have to connect Person.IdCompany to the contact of that company instead of to the company table directly?

Comment: You might be better linking Contact to Person and Person to Company. In other words, a Contact is a Person who may or may not work for a Company; a Contact is linked to a Company via the Person. You'd still be able to find all Persons linked to a Company from the Person - Company link.

Comment: Sorry, can't do that. This address book is linked to a larger database that belongs to a rent service, so a contact may refers to a company only w/o any reference person. The contact may be of a person who rent a car or of a company who rent a car. A person may occasionally work for a company, but can rent a car also for private purpose. What do you think about what I said? Person FK to Contact and FK to Company only through the company contact and not directly like now. So no more triangulation, but all pass through Contact table in a "V" pattern. Legit?

Comment: Yeah, removing the direct link from Person to Company and linking through Contact should get you what you need.

Comment: Found out the problem, but not the solution. Also using the contact of a company instead of the company in the FK same problem. Removing "ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE" works wonder. I guess that deleting the same record in Contact it would cause both to set NULL and to delete the record in Person. Btw IdContact and IdCompany in Person can't be the same and I need that if someone deletes the contact referred by IdContact the Person record have to be removed and if someone deletes the contact referred by IdCompany, then IdCompany have to be set to NULL. Any solution?

Comment: You might be able to achieve that via triggers, or in your (non-SQL) code, rather than using the cascade updates/deletes.

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to understand what I was missing. Btw if I can't solve the constraint problem I'll try those solution. Tnx for the help.